# Hibernate bidirectional one to one where both sides are owners

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to find out if and how it is possible to have a one-to-one relationship in hibernate where both sides are owners (i.e. I can do a cascade save-update while persisting **any** of the associated entities while they contain the other).
Please note that I'm looking for the **xml configuration** equivalent.

I'm providing a domain model for reference:

```
class Person {
  public int id;
  public ContactInfo info;
}

class ContactInfo {
  public int id;
  public Person person;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
  //.. init hibernate
  if (persistFromPerson) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.info = new ContactInfo();
    hibernateSession.save(person);
    hibernateSession.flush();
    assertTrue(hibernateSession.createQuery("from ContactInfo").uniqueResult().person != null);
  } else {
    ContactInfo info = new ContactInfo()
    info.person = new Person();
    hibernateSession.save(info);
    hibernateSession.flush();
    assertTrue(hibernateSession.createQuery("from Person").uniqueResult().info != null);
  }
}
```